# Cannot read property nodeType of null

Tags: javascript, html

I am studying js interaction with DOM and have several issues. The code in eloquentjs chapter 14 doesn't seem to work. Why does it output `Cannot read property nodeType of null`.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My home page</title>
    <script src="part1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My home page</h1>
    <p>Hello, I am Marijn and this is my home page.</p>
    <p>I also wrote a book! Read it
    <a href="http://eloquentjavascript.net">here</a>.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Js code:

```
function talksAbout(node, string) {
    if (node.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        for (let i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
            if (talksAbout(node.childNodes[i], string)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    } else if (node.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      return node.nodeValue.indexOf(string) > -1;
    }
  }

console.log(talksAbout(document.body, "book"));
```

Will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, your code too fast. Add an extra html attribute onto your script tag

```
 <script src="part1.js" defer="defer"></script>
```

Explanation: your js code executed before dom is loaded. You have many ways to wait for dom loaded event. You can use addEventListener and use DOMContentLoaded, or use your favorit framework. Or you can place your script tag into the end of the body. But I prefer the `defer` property because not need any additional javascript code.

Comment: But what was the mistake

Comment: Thank you very much